# how to call api inside loop using node js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I need to call API based on page number and on each and every page number API calling perform So I need to make API calling in loop based on page number.I uses request() for API Calling but when debug my code debug pointer is not going to block of response and not get response. My code is follow can any one guide me pls?

```
for (var i = 1; i <= totalpages; i++)
  request.get(
    "https://idms.dealersocket.com/api/account/getaccountlist?token=" +
      dealertoken +
      "&LayoutID=2002313&PageNumber=" +
      i +
      "&accounttype=i&accountstatus=a,c,b,o,r,s,x",
    (err, res) => {
      console.log(res);
    },
  );
```

Comment: This would be that much easier with a promise-based HTTP client (e.g. `node-fetch`) as opposed to callbacks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest installing [axios](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios) and do something like the following:

```
const axios = require('axios');

const sendGetRequest = async (url) => {
  const response = await axios.get(url);
  console.log(response);
}

for (var i = 1; i <= totalpages; i++) {
  const url = "https://idms.dealersocket.com/api/account/getaccountlist?token=" +
      dealertoken + "&LayoutID=2002313&PageNumber=" + i + "&accounttype=i&accountstatus=a,c,b,o,r,s,x"
  sendGetRequest(url);
}
```